# Bootstrap navbar hover style - how to avoid CSS Specificity

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on customising the look of a Boostrap navbar component and am having problems getting the hover state of the navbar items to work based purely on class name. At the moment I am having to use an element in my selector which I understand I should not need to do (CSS specificity?)

Here is the snippet with a navbar item I have:

```
<li class="main-menu__dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Management <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a>Overview</a><li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And my css which works:

```
.main-menu__dropdown.active,
li.main-menu__dropdown > a:hover
 {
  background-color: $navbar-item-highlight;

}
```

But I was hoping I could use the below instead:

```
.main-menu__dropdown > a:hover
```

This doesn't work for me, the variable I am using is a blue shade, but instead I get the default bootstrap off white highlight.

I am a bit of a beginner at using selectors correctly, so no doubt I have misunderstood something here!

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks

Comment: `.main-menu__dropdown.active` is a typo or have a particolar meaning. i think you  should use `.main-menu__dropdown:active`

Comment: I am using AngularJS and the .active class gets applied dynamically based on page route changes

Comment: what's wrong with `li.main-menu__dropdown > a:hover`?

Comment: I found out there is a specific .nav >ul>li>a:hover being applied by bootstrap and so I had to use an element selector to get around it

Comment: Can you just use `.nav >ul>li.main-menu__dropdown>a:hover`?

Comment: Yeah sure I probably could, I am just trying to follow some css style guides at my workplace and avoiding css specificity is a hot topic. In this instance I have to use an element selector